# Why are all 32 "cpus" on Amazon EC2 i2.8xlarge sometimes not used?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Running an i2.8xlarge EC2 instance type, I expect 32 cpus to be available and usable.  In one test on one instance I only saw 16 cpus utilized. I used `stress -c31 -t 30` to generate some cpu load but only saw 16 of the 32 cpus ever used. Specifically, htop showed cpus 1-8 and 17-24 being 100% consumed and cpus 9-16 and 25-32 idle. On a different i2.8xlarge (same OS) I confirmed with `htop` that all 32 cpus were being used.

`lscpu` output:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2500.086
BogoMIPS:              5264.79
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-31
```

Comment: `Thread(s) per core: 2` ... might that be relevant?  I wonder what `-c 14` or `-c 24` does, for example.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to track down the problem.  We were booting from an AMI that was created with a smaller instance (that only had one processor socket.)  The problem was that there was a leftover `numa=off` boot parameter in /boot/grub/grub.conf.  Once this parameter was removed and the instance was rebooted we were able to utilize all 32 cpus (all hyperthreads).